# Multiple file basename in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I have a folder with multiple pdf files and the file name are like this as below

```
1_abc.pdf
2_xyz.pdf
3_qwe.pdf
```

What is want to do is just get the first part of the file name that is

```
1
2
3
```

So I am trying to generate a rake task to get that working but I am not about to figure-out how to implement it on a multiple files.

```
namespace :request_document do
  desc "Expects to get a file or folder ..."
  task(:import_attachment, [:filename]) do |t, args|
    files = Dir.foreach("/Users/admin/Documents/Data/Attachments")
     puts files
      *This gives the list of all the files under the attachment folder*
  end
end
```

So I was thinking of using something like this

```
File.basename"1_abc.pdf".sub(/\_..*/, '')
=>  1
```

and this give the out as 1 which is what I need but I am not able to figure that out how to implement it on multiple files. Like it loops over all the files in the attachments folder and get me the first part of the filename. Please help me figure-out.

Comment: Dir[path].each { |file| puts "#{File.basename(file).sub(/\_..*/, '')}" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate over the filenames like:

```rb
Dir["/Users/admin/Documents/Data/Attachments/*"].each do |filename|
  puts File.basename(filename).sub(/\_.*/, '')
end
```

So with that the rake task would look something like this:

```rb
namespace :request_document do
  desc "Expects to get a file or folder ..."
  task(:import_attachment, [:path]) do |t, args|
    if File.directory?(args[:path])
      Dir["#{path}/*"].each do |file_path|
        puts File.basename(file_path).sub(/\_.*/, '')
      end
    else
      puts File.basename(args[:path]).sub(/\_.*/, '')
    end
  end
end
```